# What does this Assembly code do, with ascii?

Tags: assembly, ascii, x86-64, system-calls, cpu-registers

I am trying to understand the following assembly code (x86-64 att):

```
msg: .ascii "This is an examp" # please note it's examp not example

_start:

  mov $msg, %rsi
  mov $1, %rdi
  mov $1, %rdx
  mov $1, %rax
  mov $0, %rbx
  mov $16, %r9
  call exm


exm:
  cmp %rbx, %r9
  je end
  test $1, %rbx
  jnz skip
  syscall

skip:
  inc %rsi
  inc %rbx
  call exm

end:
  ret
```

1. what does it mean to store string in a register? doesn't registers hold 0/1?
2. in case it's converting ascci ti chars I know that char size is 1 byte, our string is 16 letters so we need 16 bytes and the register is only 8 bytes. how is that?
3. since rdi is 1 we are reading from screen is this true?
4. In case the sys-call fails it will return 0 and return value if stored in rax, does that mean there is a potential for endless loop?

Comment: You have a label called `msg1`, but you use `msg` in the actual code. Please clarify which one is correct.

Comment: Have you tried running it?  Have you tried single-stepping it in GDB to watch register values?  That should show you that `%rdi` gets an address, not ASCII bytes.  Also, `strace ./a.out` is a good way to see what system calls it makes before you even start figuring out exactly how/why it makes them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does it mean to store string in a register? doesn't registers hold 0/1?

I don't know what you mean by 0/1, but `msg` is a label that is basically equal to the starting address of the string. So `mov $msg, %rsi` moves the starting address of the string `"This is an examp"` into `%rsi`.

> in case it's converting ascci ti chars I know that char size is 1 byte, our string is 16 letters so we need 16 bytes and the register is only 8 bytes. how is that?

Again, the register only holds the starting address of the string.

> since rdi is 1 we are reading from screen is this true?

Not reading from the screen, *writing to the screen*. You're using the `write` system call, where you enter the file descriptor to write to in `%rdi`. `1` is `stdout`'s file descriptor, so it writes to the terminal screen.

> In case the sys-call fails it will return 0 and return value if stored in rax, does that mean there is a potential for endless loop?

`write` returns `-errno` (so a negative number) on error, not 0. Looking at the possible errors in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), I don't see any possible cause of error from your program. Since your program relies on a return value of 1 from `write` to continue calling `write`, if an error does occur, you'll call a system call that doesn't exist (since there are no negative number system calls), in which case nothing will happen and `rax` will be set to `-ENOSYS` (seems to be `-38` from a test I did) which, again, isn't a valid syscall number. I've tried editing your program to intentionally start with an invalid syscall number instead of `1` and it doesn't result in an endless loop, it just prints nothing and exits. So it doesn't seem like your program could cause an infinite loop.

I'm not sure if a proper call to write can return 0 (meaning it printed nothing) in some case from your program, but if it did, then the next call would be to `read` and your program *would* freeze until you enter some string (`read`'s arguments are very similar to `write`, so despite being a totally different syscall, it will still seemingly properly run, though since it seems like `msg` is defined in `.text`, you cannot write to it and `-EFAULT` will be returned for this too). Again, this is only assuming there is some case where `write` returns 0; I find that highly unlikely, and perhaps not even possible.

Comment: Raw asm system call errors return RAX = `-errno` codes in the -4095 .. -1 range; it's the glibc wrapper that turns that into `-1` and sets errno.  So unless you can get write to return `-EPERM`, it's not going to be `-1`.  e.g. `-EBADF` is `-9`, and `-EFAULT` is `-14`  (see `asm-generic/errno-base.h`).

Comment: More importantly, the program's behaviour isn't conditional on `write` return values.  R9 and RBX aren't modified by system calls.  There's an `if(i == max) break`, and a test for RBX being odd or even, but it doesn't look at RAX.

Comment: @PeterCordes hadn't realized that about `errno`, so fixed that, thanks. As for the return value, yeah, I assumed OP was asking if an internal error caused by `write` would result in a freeze since they weren't checking `rax`, but your point makes sense, so incorporated that into the answer too :)

Comment: Oh, I just realized that it *does* rely on `write(fd, pointer, 1) = 1` as the call number for the next `write`!!  (I think `__NR_write=STDOUT_FILENO` was chosen on purpose, along with `__NR_read=STDIN_FILENO` for x86-64, perhaps to help remember which is which, different call numbers from i386 Linux where __NR_write=4 so this wouldn't work.)  So in case of failure, later `syscall` instructions will just return `-ENOSYS` when invoked with rax = some number with its high bits set, not a valid index into the table of system calls.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right, I totally overlooked that! Edited that last part again, I *think* it's correct now.

Comment: I think `write` can only return 0 if run with length=0 (which this program can't do; syscalls don't modify RDX).  Otherwise writing no bytes would be an error.  Writing fewer bytes than requested can be a non-error, e.g. limited size pipe buffer, so normally you do need to check the write return value against your length, not just for error, in non-toy programs.  But with size=1, I *think* it's either error or 1.

Comment: But yes, if it did happen, read would block if it's connected to a TTY (not closed or redirected from a file).  IIRC, it wouldn't check permissions on the pointer until later.  (Since the program has `msg` in the `.text` section, at that point it would return `-EFAULT` from an unwriteable pointer.)  Of course the source isn't complete; without `.globl _start`, `ld` would link it with the entry point at the top of the .text section (msg, not _start).

Comment: Oh, also, you can't `ret` from `_start`, so when execution eventually falls through from the first `call exm` into exm again and runs `ret` (with RSP pointing at `argc`), it will segfault on code fetch from address `1`.  But that's after making all the syscalls it's going to make.  I suspect the querent cut this down to a less-than-complete [mcve], if it's an example they got from somewhere.  (I tried it by moving the string to *after* the code)

Comment: @PeterCordes forgot that `msg` seems to be defined in `.text` (I defined it in `.data` when testing), fixed that.

Comment: Why would you want it in writeable .data?  `.rodata` would be the normal place for it, or part of the .text section is basically fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's a bad habit I got from when I didn't know that you could define them in `.text` and `.rodata` was a thing :P Every now and again I still tend to forget.